# Can't delete the node from the end of a linked list

Tags: c, list, data-structures, linked-list

I have a problem about deleting the last node of my linked list. I put printf functions to check and locate the error but I can't find it. This my code for deleting the last node from an unsorted linked list. At the end you will see four add functions and they are working successfully. The only broken part is deleting from the end.

```
void del_Node(LIST* list, int counter) {

    if( counter == 0 )
        return;

    NODE* temp = list->header;

    int count=1;

    if( list->header == NULL ) {
        printf("The list is already EMPTY\n");
        return;
    }

    while( count != counter ) {
        temp = temp->next;
        count++;
    }

    printf("%s %s\n", temp->first_name, temp->last_name);

    if( list->counter == 1 ) { // Condition for deleting the last node of the linked list

        list->header = NULL;
        list->tail = NULL;

        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->pre = NULL;

        list->counter--;

    }

    else if( list->header == temp ) { // Condition for deleting from the beginnig

        list->header = temp->next;

        printf("%s listenin basından silindi\n", temp->first_name);

        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->pre = NULL;

        list->counter--;

    }

    else if ( list->tail == temp ) { // Condition for deleting from the end

        list->tail = temp->pre;

        printf("%s normal listenin tailinden silindi yeni tail %s\n", temp->first_name, temp->pre->first_name);

        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->pre = NULL;

        list->counter--;

    }

    else { // Condition from deleting from the middle

        temp->pre->next = temp->next;

        temp->next->pre = temp->pre;

        printf("%s normal listede %s------%s arasından silindi\n",temp->first_name, temp->next->first_name, temp->pre->first_name);

        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->pre = NULL;

        list->counter--;

    }

    del_fn_name(list, temp);
    del_ln_name(list, temp);
    del_bdt(list, temp);
    del_city(list, temp);

    free(temp);

    printf("List->counter = %d %d %d\n", list->counter, list->fn_count, list->ln_count );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you forgot `temp->pre->next = NULL;`

Comment: i am just recognized it from other delete functions and preparing to write "sorry mates i fixed". i spent mant hours for this stupid mistake. :). thanks mate for your help.

Comment: @user743898: also note it seems you forgot at deleting the beginning: temp->next->pre = (something)... and to be honest I didn't have a look at deleting from the middle, but I would have a looked on it to if I were you. good luck:)

Comment: yes another mistake your are right :D. thanks for your help and suggestions :D